# jHipster production build error. Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed

Tags: java, npm, jhipster

I've generated **monolithic application** using **jHipster 4.9.0** and when I run **mvn -Pprod package** the build failed with the following errors.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project itob-p: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I've also reinstalled Nodejs containing npm package 5.3.0 and also deleted the folder node_modules and re install npm on the generated folder but got no success. I'm stuck and unable to identify the problem if i'm doing something wrong please point it out.

What is done so far :

1) Operating system = Windows 7 64bit

2) generated source code of nonpolitical application [yo jhipster]

3) Database postgrase

4) OAuth2

5) mvn -Pprod package

6) **successfully deploys on Pivotal Cloud Foundry in [Dev] mode**

Note this issue occurs while making build for production.

here is the complete stack of this command.
I'm unable to identify and understand the problem. Please help me and if you have any kind of suggestion please share.
Here is the complete stack of error.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) @ itob-p ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2
[INFO] yarn run v1.1.0
[INFO] $ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[ERROR] warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarde
d as-is to the scripts.
[INFO] Starting compilation using the angular compiler.
[ERROR] (node:7220) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated. Use     Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule instead.
[INFO] Angular compilation done, starting webpack bundling.
[ERROR] TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
[ERROR]     at checkUnreachable     (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescrip
t.js:20770:30)
[ERROR]     at bindChildrenWorker     (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-    wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:19014:17)
[ERROR]     at bindChildren (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js
:18969:17)
[ERROR]     at bind (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:20199:2
1)
[ERROR]     at bindSourceFile (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.
js:18588:17)
[ERROR]     at Object.bindSourceFile (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\type
script.js:18539:9)
[ERROR]     at initializeTypeChecker (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\type
script.js:44253:20)
[ERROR]     at Object.createTypeChecker (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\lib\t
ypescript.js:23058:9)
[ERROR]     at getDiagnosticsProducingTypeChecker (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typesc
ript\lib\typescript.js:70194:93)
[ERROR]     at Object.getGlobalDiagnostics (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\node_modules\typescript\li
b\typescript.js:70570:53)
[ERROR]     at Tsc.typeCheck (C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-    wrapped\src\tsc.js:166:23)
[ERROR]     at C:\Users\hassnan.ali\Desktop\del.me\postgres2\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:122:23
[ERROR]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation     about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13:43 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-13T13:08:13+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project itob-p: Failed to run task: 'yarn ru
n webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: `yarn` uses `npm`. Are you installing it too?

Comment: @canillas yarn is already installed and working fine.

Comment: but is `npm` installed?

Comment: @canillas yes its installed.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade with `jhipster upgrade`command?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I do not want to update my jhipster as I want to use jhipster 4.9.0 because I need spring oauth2. and 4.10.0 container open id connect. If jhipster upgrade command does not effect my source code then i can upgrade.. what do you recommend ??

Comment: Just try on a clone of your project and see by yourself

Comment: thank you for replying @GaëlMarziou. I'll try.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Just run `yarn` and if it is needed, update it. And try again. It works for me.